# ¿Cómo quitar el último div usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una lista de `div` y después de eliminar uno de ellos, me gustaría quitar el último elemento de `div`.

Logré retirar un elemento por click, ahí desordenado números cualquiera. No me gusto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que ordene el número, primero el último campo `nombre 4` después borrar campo `nombre 3` y así sucesivamente hasta borrar el `nombre 1` ¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
    var maxField = 4; 
    var xField = 0; 
    var addButton = $('.addInput'); 
    var addHtml = $('.addElement');
 
    //Agregar input
    $(addButton).click(function(){ 
        if(xField < maxField){
         xField++; 
            $(addHtml).append('<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"><div class="form-group"><label for="campo_pr">Nombre '+xField+' (*)</label></div></div><div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7"><div class="input-group form-group" style="display: inline-table; !important"><input type="text" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="removeInput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></a></span></div></div>');          
        }
    });

    //Borrar input
    $(document).on('click', '.removeInput', function(e){ 
      
     $(this).closest('div').parent('div').prev().remove();

        $(this).closest('div').parent('div').remove();
        xField--;
         
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<div class="addElement">
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
  <div class="form-6roup">
      <label for="campo_pr">Nombre (*)</label>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">
  <div class="input-group form-group" style="display: inline-table; !important">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campo_pr">          
   <span class="input-group-addon">
          <a href="#" class="addInput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a>
         </span>           
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, que idioma hablas, esta un poco rara tu gramatica, en fin , si por ejemplo un elemento que tenga información es borrado como se debe comportar tu programa? , lo eliminaría con todo y la información, o la información se pasa a otro lado?

Comment: Creo que el titulo debería ser "mantener orden de numeración después de remover" o algo asi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agrégale una clase a tu label, luego usa $().each() para iterar sobre ellos

```js
var maxField = 4; 
    var xField = 0; 
    var addButton = $('.addInput'); 
    var addHtml = $('.addElement');
 
    //Agregar input
    $(addButton).click(function(){ 
        if(xField < maxField){
         xField++; 
            $(addHtml).append('<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"><div class="form-group"><label for="campo_pr" class="label-nombre">Nombre '+xField+' (*)</label></div></div><div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7"><div class="input-group form-group" style="display: inline-table; !important"><input type="text" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="removeInput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></a></span></div></div>');          
        }
    });

    //Borrar input
    $(document).on('click', '.removeInput', function(e){ 
      
     $(this).closest('div').parent('div').prev().remove();

        $(this).closest('div').parent('div').remove();
        xField--;
        
        $( ".label-nombre" ).each(function( index ) {
        
          $( this ).html('Nombre '+(index+1).toString()+' (*)');
        });
         
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<div class="addElement">
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
  <div class="form-6roup">
      <label for="campo_pr">Nombre (*)</label>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-7">
  <div class="input-group form-group" style="display: inline-table; !important">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="campo_pr">          
   <span class="input-group-addon">
          <a href="#" class="addInput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></a>
         </span>           
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cuenta `.last()` para seleccionar el último elemento y `.remove()` para quitar elementos.

Ejemplo:

Se incluyen 5 elementos con la etiqueta `div`. Cada uno con un ordinal, del primero al quinto. Sólo mostrarán 4.

```js
$("div").last().remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Primero</div>
<div>Segundo</div>
<div>Tercero</div>
<div>Cuarto</div>
<div>Quinto</div>
```